# How often do airline pilots actually have to avoid other aircraft that ATC did not tell them about at cruise altitude?

Tags: airliner, airline-operations, instrument-flight-rules, see-and-avoid

I know any pilot flying in VMC, whether under VFR or IFR, must "see and avoid." How often do airline pilots actually "see" and have to "avoid" other traffic at cruise altitude without being told about the traffic by ATC? Can it happen without someone doing something wrong?

Comment: It's possible if someone departs from a clearance, but that's what TCAS is for.  The vertical separation is only 1000 ft at the FLs above 280, and because of GPS, everybody is exactly on the airway centerline, so when someone passes above or below on your airway, they pass precisely overhead or underneath, 1000 ft above/below. They look like they are coming straight at you until they are a couple miles out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the U.S., at **cruise altitude** for airline operations (normally above FL180 and in class A airspace) it should never happen because all aircraft are operating under IFR and being positively separated by ATC.

Comment: In theory. I was on a corporate customer acceptance flt, flying a big circular route while the customer checked out the cabin systems. We made a boo boo in the FMS entries and left out a waypoint in the 12 or so that made up our big circle. Airplane started turning toward the waypoint AFTER the one we were supposed to turn to, making our turn sharper than it would have. Kindly ATC said, "XXXX I see you're heading toward waypoint Y instead of waypoint X. Would like like me to amend your clearance?" We looked at each other; yikes. "Yes we'll take the revised clearance and thank you VERY much".

Answer (score -3):

#### Above FL180, basically never. Below, just like any other VFR pilot

Expanding on 757toga's answer, in the US there are altitudes above which it is not legal to fly except under IFR. At those altitudes, there should never be anyone. However, that leaves flights over international waters as well as flights below those altitudes.

Below 18000', there is no positive control of the airspace. The FAA politely asks that VFR pilots cruise at altitudes ending in `500'`, e.g. `3500'`, `10500`, `14500'`, etc... However, the request is not a requirement, in that not everyone in the sky is is cruising. There are many, many users of the sky, such as gliders, aerobatics, balloons which would not be expected to be in level flight.

So IFR flights below FL180 still need to aggressively practice see-and-avoid. Airlines will fly at those altitudes often enough when coming into and out of airports, so they will need to see-and-avoid just like a normal VFR pilot.

The only time an IFR pilot can be sure there's no one at a sub-FL180 altitude is when flying in a cloud and thus knowing there are no VFR pilots around.

ATC will provide guidance if there are transponder or radar blips, but there is no universal transponder requirement and so many planes are invisible to ATC.

That being said, the sky is a very, very, very empty place. The number of times I've had to see and *avoid*, as opposed to simply *see* is... 0? (I'm not counting flying in a gaggle with other glider pilots.) I imagine most pilots are in a similar boat.

Comment: 14 CFR 91.159 is **not** phrased as a request...

Comment: The only times that I have had to see and avoid another airplane were within Alert areas for high amount of flight training. Airplanes in those areas usually do a lot more climbing, descending, and turning due to the nature of operations.

Comment: "Below 18000', there is no positive control of the airspace." -> What about class B airspace?

Comment: @Bianfable that's a fair point, but those airspaces are few and far between.

Comment: @randomhead, sure, and I'm assuming you were one of the downvoters. Please note that the 91.159 is only applicable to *level cruising flight*.  I've updated my answer to make it more clear how 91.159 is not applicable to the OP's question. We are frequently up and down the airspace within the mode-C veil, in gliders and aerobatic experimentals with neither ADBS nor transponders.

Comment: @downvoters in general, I think you should reconsider your downvote. Pilots who see the airspace as *only* IFR cruise or *VFR* cruise are some of the biggest threats to users who are pure VFR. It's galling that there are so many of us who seemingly never look outside our cockpits, because too many of us feel 91.159 and ADSB gives us invincibility.

Comment: Well, the question was about airliners at *cruise* altitude, which tends to imply above 18,000' MSL.  So the answer was *broader* than the question, but not in any way that was unclear or confusing.  I strongly agree w/ a lot of the content in answer, and in comment immediately above.  Shame about all the dv's.  Rephrase to delete "politely asks" but keep the other content and maybe they'll come to their senses and reconsider.

Comment: There's a new question here somewhere in the making, what is the definition of "cruise" anyway, on a long XC flight if I choose a continuous steady climb to the midpoint and then a continuous descent, flying VFR below 18,000', am I violating any reg? How low would my climb or descent rate have to fall before I were considered to be "cruising"?  Someone ought to ask that question.

Comment: @quietflyer that's an excellent point, and why I had the "politely ask" phrase. 91.159 mentions level cruise only, so if you are climbing and descending you are not violating any regs, nor even, I would argue, behaving inappropriately. AFAICT, 91.159 is toothless and probably only can be enforced as part of a broader 91.13 administrative action.

Comment: Wow, still collecting downvotes. Literally spoke about this topic with a glider DPE a week ago and we both concluded that there is no requirement for aircraft to be at those altitudes. People, please keep your eyes open for the many, many users of the space who are not at all visible to ATC. Just two weeks ago, I was thermalling at 7k' with Spirit jets passing below at 5k'...